# Where is the Thrift format specification?

Tags: thrift, specifications, dataformat

Although Thrift format is relatively widely used (and project still alive), I haven't been able to find specification for the underlying data format. Or formats, given that there are apparently at least two formats; standard one, and compact format.

Given its wide usage I am hoping it is just my poor google-fu, and a specification or specifications exist (outside of source code). If so, please share!

EDIT: Java source code is not too bad for figuring out format; see TBinaryProtocol.java and TCompactBinaryProtocol.java; which contain primitives, called by generated classes (which extend TBase)

EDIT2: While it does not contain format spec, "[the missing guide](http://diwakergupta.github.com/thrift-missing-guide/)" is good reading.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same problem and therefore decided to write a specification of the Thrift binary and compact protocol.

The spec is now available in the Thrift repo: https://github.com/apache/thrift/tree/master/doc/specs

*Old answer:*

You can find it here: https://erikvanoosten.github.io/thrift-missing-specification/

Answer (score 12):

The format for a Thrift message depends on the serialization protocol chosen.  You can serialize a Thrift object using one of many protocols, including the TBinaryProtocol, TCompactProtocol, TJSONProtocol, and other obscure options.  The protocol is described abstractly in the original [Thrift Whitepaper PDF](http://thrift.apache.org/static/files/thrift-20070401.pdf) in terms of the API, but is not currently defined anywhere in the Thrift apache project.

The TCompactProtocol protocol is slightly better defined [on the thrift wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/thrift/New_compact_binary_protocol) but not in simple terms.

Until better documentation is available, you can also examine the Python library code alongside the Python `struct` module documentation as another option.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I know difference between original TBinary and TCompactProtocol. json protocol seems kind of useless so I don't care, but would definitely be nice to have defs of first two. But reading sources is easy enough in this case so that'll work.

Answer (score 2):

There are two binary encodings, compact and and non-compact.

Usually you will find the compact protocol in the wild:

> https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/doc/specs/thrift-compact-protocol.md

While the non-compact protocol is probably a legacy protocol:

> https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/doc/specs/thrift-binary-protocol.md

With this being a rough overview of the specification:

> https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/doc/specs/thrift-protocol-spec.md